# C++ how to access class member function between instances

Tags: c++, class

Is there a way to access a specific Class instance's member function within a member function definition?  Let me clarify what I mean in a pseudo code below.

Thanks!

```
// A Class called Dog
class Dog
{
public:
void eat();
void drink();
//... More code here
};

void Dog::eat()
{
//How do I always access dog1.drink() here, regardless of which instance calls it?
}
//... More code here
// Instances of Dog
Dog dog1, dog2;
```

Comment: Did you try `dog1.drink();`? (you have to declare `dog1` *before* the function that calls it.)

Comment: You'd have to have a reference to that instance in a static/global variable.

Comment: It seems that your dog1 is a special Dog, the very one that eats in the herd. I would rethink the hierarchy.

Comment: How about making the drink() function static ?

Comment: you could pass the "other dog" in as a constructor param and store it as a member variable. the up side is that this other dog it "dynamic" and need not be a static singleton, the down side is that whenever a dog is constructed, the caller must have reference to "other dog". it depends on the actual use case as to wether this is better than just using a static/global

Comment: @ezio making it static will not have access to dog1 in particular, it will be just be a global function

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make `dog1` drink, you simply call:

```
dog1.drink();
```

It makes no difference whether you write this inside a member function of `Dog` or not. There is no need to overthink things here.

Note: Like any other use of a global variable, the global variable has to be declared before the code that uses it.